# remove zero in mysql field using join

Tags: mysql

> code = 00000000005555
>
> 2nd option code = 00000000000555

hi i am try to find out same function like ltrim() of php

```
SELECT * FROM db1.stock JOIN db2.prodinfo ON replace(db2.prodinfo.code,0000000000,'') = replace(db1.stock.code,0000000000,'') WHERE db1.stock.InvNo ='12' and db2.prodinfo.Cat = 'super'
```

> i rum this temporary. becuse zero might be increase and decrease i
>   example above. i am just want to remove zero in this query

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try by casting it into numeric,

```
SELECT * 
FROM db1.stock JOIN db2.prodinfo ON 
          CAST(db2.prodinfo.code AS SIGNED) = CAST(db1.stock.code AS SIGNED) 
WHERE db1.stock.InvNo ='12' and db2.prodinfo.Cat = 'super'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM db1.stock JOIN db2.prodinfo ON 
CAST(db2.prodinfo.code AS DECIMAL(15,0)) = CAST(db1.stock.code AS AS DECIMAL(15,0)) 
WHERE db1.stock.InvNo ='12' and db2.prodinfo.Cat = 'super'
```